# Determining a path through a graph that minimises the average distance/standard deviation of the distances

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I've been asked to find a path between two vertices on a complete graph, say A and B. Each edge has a weight, and the path needs to travel from A to B. However the problem is not to determine the shortest distance, but a path that minimises the average of the distances (which is defined as the total distance divided by the number of edges) and if possible minimises the standard deviation of the distances.

For example if A to B direct is 3, but A to C to B is 5, this would result in an average of 2.5.

Comment: So what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: @FlorisClaassens I've only thought about how to approach it (it's late at night). I was thinking of finding the shortest path for  for each path of a certain length (where length is the number of edges), however I only know the basic shortest path algorithm (Dijkstra's algorithm), which is what I teach.

Comment: I'll add the graph is a complete graph with 35 vertices so any algorithms that can help would be great

Comment: Can you use an edge multiple times? Because in that case I suspect for many paths you would have to find a "minimal" cycle which you then walk an infinite amount of time to get a path with average length similar to the average length of the cycle.

Comment: In general I suspect an adjusted Dijkstra's algorithm applied infinite times might work. For this you would have to look at limit behaviour.

Comment: Each edge can only be included once

Comment: I think you could adjust the Floyd-Warshall algorithm to give the solution!